# Одна переменная на два класса Java

Tags: java

Мне нужно, что бы с переменной i в классе A мог работать и класс B. 
Как это сделать? Гугл не помог ._.

Я решил разбить один класс на несколько, ибо начал путаться уже.
Другой класс должен работать с переменной m
P.S. Код максимально отвратителен, но я пока учусь

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x, xx, row=0, col=0, komp=0, g=0;
        String x1 = "X";
        String x2 = "O";
        int[][] m = {   
            { 1, 2, 3 },
            { 4, 5, 6 },
            { 7, 8, 9 } 
        };
        Random r = new Random();

        if(g!=10) {
            for(g=0;g<9;g++) {
                Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Введите значение");
                x = scn.nextInt();
                if(x>9||x<1) {
                    System.out.println("Ты блин васян не вводи число больше 3 или меньше 1!");
                } else {
                    for(row=0;row<m.length;row++) {
                        for(int col=0;col<m[row].length;col++) {
                            if(m[row][col]==x) {
                                m[row][col] = 50;
                            } else {
                                if(m[row][col]=='X'||m[row][col]=='O')
                                    System.out.println("ЗАНЯТО");
                            }

                            row=0;
                            col=0;
                            x = r.nextInt();
                            if(m[row][col]==x) {
                                m[row][col] = 40;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите Ваш код пожалуйста...

Comment: Тоже эта проблема попробуй
нужную переменную вот так написать
public static (Тип переменной) (Название) = (Значение не обязательно(если не пишите значение равно не надо));
Ржу) (Ты блин васян не вводи число больше 3 или меньше 1!)

Answer (score 4):

Если классы независимы, то для этого достаточно объявить переменную `i` в классе `A` со спецификатором `public` или `"package-local"` (если оба класса в одном пакете).

Если же имеет место ситуация

```
class B extends A
```

то для того, чтобы из класса `B` получить доступ к переменной `A::i` достаточно отсутствия у неё спецификатора `private`.

**Дополнение**

Поскольку в данном случае функция, из которой нужно получить доступ к переменной, статическая, то переменная также должна быть статической. То есть, для решения задачи нужно написать, например, так:

```
class Main {
    public static int[][] m = ...
}
```

или же, ограничиваясь доступом только из текущего пакета,

```
class Main {
    static int[][] m = ...
}
```

Comment: Как вот это сделать общим? оба совета не помогли -_- int[][] m =
      {   { 1, 2, 3 },
          { 4, 5, 6 },
          { 7, 8, 9 } };

Comment: Общим для кого? У Вас одна-единственная функция, не говоря уже о классе.

Comment: Эта функция находится в классе Main, а я хочу, что бы с этой функцией мог работать и класс List, который находится в том же пакете, что и Main

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Теперь можно и по-человечески код написать :D

Comment: А не подскажешь, как определить в этом массиве наличие определенного числа?

Comment: `boolean found=false;
for (int i=0; i<3 && !found; ++i)
    for (int j=0; j<3 && !found; ++j)
        if (m[i][j] == OWN_NUM)
            found = true;`

Answer (score 2):

сделай её протектед и тогда доступ будет из того же пэкэджа, либо паблик

Comment: модификатор private и гетер?

Comment: @barmaglott не наш метод.

Comment: @zenden2k `protected` даёт доступ только наследникам, для пакета - `"package-local"`, т.е. без модификаторов.

Comment: @kff, не только наследникам, но и в пакете тоже https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: @Russtam Упс... Извиняюсь. Тяжёлое наследие C++.. ;)